# How should an HTTP server pass request parameters to an script?

Tags: c, shell, http, server, pipe

I'm building an HTTP server in C, which supports execution of PHP and Python scripts. I'm in the process of adding script support, and it's working fine, but I don't know what the convention is for passing the querystring and POST data to a script.

Should I pass it all via argv when calling the script? Or via stdin after calling the script?

I've been searching extensively, but haven't been able to find where scripts expect to receive the querystring and POST data.

Comment: There isn't really a convention. I would consider the argv as a natural option. After all it is a remote call of a sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention for a Web server executing a program or script to handle an HTTP request is [CGI (Common Gateway Interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). In CGI, the query string is passed in an environment variable called `QUERY_STRING`, and POST data is passed via standard input.